# Import data from CSV file to Amazon Web Services RDS MySQL database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have created a Relational Database (MySQL) hosted on Amazon Web Services. What I would like to do next is, import the data in my local CSV files into this database. I would really appreciate if someone provides me an outline on how to go about it.Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is easiest and most hands-off by using MySQL command line.  For large loads, consider spinning up a new EC2 instance, installing MySQL CL tools, and transferring your file to that machine.  Then, after connecting to your database via CL, you'd do something like:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/upload.csv' INTO TABLE myTable;
```

Also options to match your file's details and ignore header (plenty more in the docs)

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/upload.csv' INTO TABLE myTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

If you're hesitant to use CL, download MySQL Workbench.  It connects no prob to AWS RDS.

Closing thoughts:

- [MySQL LOAD DATA Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)
- AWS' Aurora RDS is MySQL-compatible so command works there too
- "LOCAL" flag actually transfers the file from your client machine (where you're running the command) to the DB server.  Without LOCAL, the file must be on the DB server (not possible to transfer it there in advance with RDS)
- **Works great on huge files too!** Just sent a 8.2GB file via this method (260 million rows).  Took just over 10 hours from a t2-medium EC2 to db.t2.small Aurora
- Not a solution if you need to watch out for unique keys or read the CSV row-by-row and change the data before inserting/updating

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging and found this official AWS documentation on how to import data from any source to MySQL hosted on RDS.

It is a very detailed step by step guide and icludes an explanation on how to import CSV files.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.AnySource.html

Basically, each table must have its own file. Data for multiple tables cannot be combined in the same file. Give each file the same name as the table it corresponds to. The file extension can be anything you like. For example, if the table name is "sales", the file name could be "sales.csv" or "sales.txt", but not "sales_01.csv".

Whenever possible, order the data by the primary key of the table being loaded. This drastically improves load times and minimizes disk storage requirements.

There is another option to [import data to MySQL database](https://www.alooma.com/integrations/mysql), you can use an external tool Alooma that can do the data import  for you in real time.

Comment: There's also MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how large is your file, but if it is under 1GB I found that DataGrip imports smaller files without any issues: https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/
You get nice mapping tool and graphical IDE to play around. DataGrip is available as a trial for 30 days free.

I am experiencing myself RDS connection dropouts with bigger files like > 2GB. Not sure if it is about the DataGrip or AWS side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to develop a script in your language of choice to connect to the database and import it.

If your database is internet accessible then you can run that script locally. If it is in a private subnet then you can either run that script on an EC2 instance with access to the private subnet or on lambda connected to your VPC. You should really only use lambda if you expect runtime to be less than 5 minutes or so.

Edit: Note that lambda only supports a handful of languages

> AWS Lambda supports code written in Node.js (JavaScript), Python, Java
>   (Java 8 compatible), and C# (.NET Core).